# Resources cannot be accessed in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, resx

i have a solution in which i have a web project and couple of other projects. I have added another project that has nothing but a resx file. I have referenced this resource project dll into the web project. is there any possible way i could access the resource in dll into the aspx page. For ex:
 `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,ButtonName %>">`
The ButtonName must be accessed from the resourcedll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the namespace into the aspx page using @Import page directive.

```
<%@ Import Namespace = "MyProject.Resources" %>
```

Now to use the resource for setting the property of a Server control, you need to call DataBind() method at the page level on your Page_Load() event. (can be invoked for specific controls also).

```
    Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataBind();
        }
    }
    in your aspx page:
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text = '<%# ProjectResources.CmdBtn %>' />
```

make sure you make the resource class and the resource key property public, its internal by default.

Comment: it still complains as follows :  The resource object with key 'String1' was not found.

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,String1 %>" />` I have imported it as ResourceFile.Resources where ResourceFile is project name and Resources is resx file name